# Can't submit build for external testing on TestFlight

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

I'm trying to submit a build version of my app to external testing on app store connect TestFlight. I've already created the external test team and added all the testers. The problem is when I try to add the build to that specific team.

This is the error:

[image: Image of the erro]

On the "Test information" section, I provided the fields descibed bellow:

- Beta App Description
- Feedback Email
- All the contacting info (Including Sign-in required)

It's important to notice that I can submit the same build to an internal test without any problem. Another important thing is that this error was not occurring a few days ago. I aways do the same process and never had a problem until now.

Any suggestions? I've been stuck here for a while.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1772220)

Comment: I was having this exact same issue, so I did some digging and landed here on this (not yet answered question).
What did help me was removing the external user group on the "iOS Builds" page and re-adding it. First of all, the dialog that asked for the things to test had a button "Submit to Review". After closing it with that button, the status has now switched to "Waiting for Review" 